# Graph with colored edges: shortest paths with at most k color changes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a directed graph with coloured, weighted edges. There are 2 colours. Each edge can have only 1 colour. I want to find shortest path with limited changes of colours. From one vertex there can be max 2 edges with 2 different colors going out and 2 edges with 2 different colors going in.

For example in this graph:

[image]

Shortest path with maximum of 3 colour changes will be `9`
With max `0` colour changes shortest path is `6+1+4=11`, etc.

My solution is to recursively visit all possible paths and exchange if recursion find a better one which makes this problem exponential.

Is there a non-exponential solution to this problem?

Comment: So what is the input of your problem? The graph and the maximum number of colour changes allowed?

Comment: Is the goal to find the lowest-cost solution using at most k color changes, or to find the cheapest path out of all the paths that use the fewest color changes?

Comment: The graph, start vertex, end vertex and max colour changes.
Yes, the goal is to find lowest-cost solution using at most k colour changes

Comment: Are there any bounds on the value of k?

Comment: There are non, i mean number of max changes is given and it's equal to or greater than 0

Comment: One last question - do all the edges have nonnegative weights?

Comment: (I'm asking because I believe there's a poly-time algorithm if the edges are nonnegative and I suspect there is no poly-time algorithm if the edges can be negative.)

Comment: They all have weights greater than 0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved in time O(nm + n<sup>2</sup> log n) by running Dijkstra's algorithm on an appropriately-constructed graph.

To motivate the intuition for where we're going, let's assume for now that the optimal path makes at most one color change and starts by following a red edge. The path therefore either follows no blue edges, in which case we only follow red edges, or it follows some number of red edges, then some number of blue edges.

Think about what happens if you transform G as follows:

- Begin by copying the nodes in the graph twice to give two layers G0 and G1. We'll denote the copy of node v in G0 as v0 and the copy of node v in G1 as v1.
- For each blue edge (u0, v0), replace that edge with the edge (u0, v1).
- Delete all red edges from G1.

You can think of this graph as two copies of G stacked on top of one another with some tweaks to the edges. Specifically, edges running inside of G0 are all red, and the blue edges take you down to G1. There are then no red edges in G1.

Think about what a path in this graph looks like. If you stay purely in G0, it consists only of red edges. If you start in G0 and end up in G1, then the path starts of by following some number of red edges, then at least one blue edge, and then some larger number of blue edges. Therefore, any path in this graph will have exactly one color change involved.

You can use this graph to find the shortest path from a node u to a node v that makes at most one color change. Start by running Dijkstra's algorithm starting at u, and look at the distances of v0 and v1. The distance to v0 is the length of the shortest path to v0 that makes no color changes. The distance to v1 is the length of the shortest path to v1 that makes at most one color change. The shorter of these two distances then gives you the length of the shortest path from u to v that makes at most one color change.

We can extend this trick to work for any number of steps k as follows. Create k copies of G, called G0, G1, G2, ..., G(k-1). Assuming the path starts with a red edge, we can then change the graph as follows. Make all blue edges in G0 instead run from G0 to G1. Then, make all red edges in G1 run from G1 to G2. Then, make all blue edges in G2 run from G2 to G3, etc. Finally, delete all edges out of G(k-1) that are not of the color leading into G(k-1). This graph maintains the same property as before - any path from a node u0 to a node v_r represents a path from u to v that makes exactly r color changes, assuming the first edge is red. The best path making at most r color changes can then be found by looking at the lowest cost of the paths to v_0, v_1, ..., v_(k-1).

This approach so far assumes that the first step is red, but we're not guaranteed that's the case. But that's okay - we can run this algorithm once assuming the first step is red and once assuming the first step is blue and take the best of both options.

So how expensive is this? Well, if we get at most k color changes, the graph we construct will have a total of O(nk) nodes and O(mk) edges, so constructing it will take time O(k(m + n)). Running Dijkstra's in the graph to find the shortest paths to all the destination nodes then takes time O(mk + nk log nk), so the total runtime is O(mk + nk log nk).

We can actually upper-bound this at O(mn + n<sup>2</sup> log n) for the following reason: since all edges have *strictly positive* weight, we know that no path can make more than n - 1 color changes. If a path did, it would have at least n edges in it, so it would have a cycle. That cycle has strictly positive cost, so we could improve the cost by eliminating the cycle. Therefore, if k ≥ n, we can just cap k at n. Plugging in k = n to the above expression gives the asymptotic runtime of O(mn + n<sup>2</sup> log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when i get enough reputation i'll give you that points :P
I'll check that deeply later and give a response if it works or ask questions. Thanks again!

Comment: Great explanation as usual :)  A minor point: "any path from a node u0 to a node v_r represents a path from u to v that makes at most r color changes" is correct, but it would be clearer to change "at most r" to "exactly r" so that its converse is also true.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's a good point. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to run Dijkstra's algorithm,  but use a two-level heap instead.

The two main structures as as followed.

1. A hashmap/dictionary, that maps the number of color changes to a min-heap containing all active paths with that exact number of color changes.
2. A k-way merge heap, that takes in the heaps that are being mapped to in #1, the current min distance and yields the heap with the smallest distance.

The psudeocode for the main functions are as followed:

- ExtractMin(): Extracts the min from the k-way heap. This leads to the # color change heap that min was part of. The new min  is extracted from the color change heap, and is then added back to the k-way heap (mapped to it's color change heap).
- add(path, length, number of color changes): Looks up the heap with for that number of color changes and inserts the path into it, creating the heap if it doesn't already exist. if that is the new min for that heap, then the min for that number of color change heap is changed within the k-way merge heap, via decrease key, with the only value replaced with the new one.

In other words, a heap for each number of color changes is used and the min of each of those heaps are inserted into another min heap, which is used to find the actual min.

To prevent it form being equivalent to the standard Dijkstra's algorithm, you simply don't add paths that have too many color changes to the two level heap. You could use something like:

```
if number_color_changes <= max_color_changes:
    data_structure.add(path, length, number_color_changes)
```

This can also be used to find the min paths for each number of color changes less than or equal to the min number of color changes.

As for handling the color changes themselves. Each path is associated with a counter and during the expansion step of Dijkstra's,a check is made to determine if the edge color changes and the new path's counter is updated to reflect that.

Asymptotic performance should be about the same as Dijkstra's algorithm using the same type of heap.